# blender 2.78c lagging too much in window 10

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, windows

when I working on my first project (more than basic use) it was got working nice and smooth but when start to use it little bit for advance use its got slow and star to lag and seem not responding to any action then i have have to restart my laptop to put thihgs right

my laptop spec are as follow

- OS-window 10 64 bit
- RAM-4096 MB
- HARD DISK-290 GB  processor-Intel(R)Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.5GHz
- display- intel(R)HD Graphics 3000 (1664mb of memory)

Comment: what do you mean with more advance, like particle hair, over 100 000 vertices etc.

Comment: Intel graphics cards are known to cause problems with Blender, they also provide low performance, so if your scene is too complex your computer won't be able to keep up.

Comment: yes you are right nils, I do problem on particles hair when set over 2500